# Store and retrieve chained jquery effects/objects in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to dynamically change jquery effects by storing the chained objects in a variable and concatenating to selector later, so that i have the latest required effect when it needs to exec.
i store a predifined set of jquery chained effects - fadeOut().end().next().fadeIn() - in the data-effect attr, which can change, so i need to reference back to it via a variable to add the effects to $(contentDiv) selector.
So something like; $(selector)effect, won't work.

```
var effects = document.getElementById('effect').getAtttribute('data-effect');
$(contentsDiv).effects;
```

Comment: In your case a clarification of your question would help more than adding a bounty

Comment: What do you mean with `$(selector)`, is it an select field or just a container that display data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this (updated):

```
var effect = "fadeOut.end.next.fadeIn";
var $obj = $(contentsDiv);
$.each(effect.split('.'),
    function(key, value) {
        $obj = $obj[value]();
    });
```

Comment: I updated the code to apply a chain of effects. May be that comes closer to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean here. What your code does is look for an unspecified method on the jQuery object called `effects`.

If you mean that you want to store the contents of the attribute 'data-effect' and then apply that to another element later, you can do that like this:

```
var effects = $('#effect').attr('data-effect');
$(contentsDiv).attr('data-effect', effects);
```

Comment: Hi @Johnathan, no i store a predifined set of jquery chained effects in the data-effect attr, which can change, so i need to reference back to it via a variable to add the effects to $(contentDiv) selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data) to store a function at a jQuery object; [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to call stored function with `this` set to [`jQuery()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery) object having selector parameter `contentsDiv`.

You could also utilize [`.promise()`](http://api.jquery.com/promise), [`.then()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then) to call additional functions when all animations of each element passed to effects function have completed.

```js
function fx() {
  // `.contents .a`: `contentsDiv`
  console.log(this); 
  return this.fadeOut(1000).promise().then(function() {
    return $(this).next().fadeIn(1000).promise().then(function() {
      // `.contents .b`: `.nextElementSibling of `.contents .a`
      console.log(this); 
    });
  });
}

var effects = $("#effects").data("effect", fx);

var contentsDiv = ".contents .a";
// pass jQuery object as first parameter to `.call()`
// to set `this` within `fx` function at `$("#effects").data().effect`
effects.data().effect.call($(contentsDiv))
.then(function() {
  console.log("effects complete")
});
```

```css
.b {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="effects"></div>
<div class="contents">contents<br>
<div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="b">b</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what effects you want. 
But you can use Jquery Effect https://api.jqueryui.com/category/effects/
Please have a look at my code I have created. 
I have use array shift and push to repeat the effects using the data-attribute you have used.
https://jsfiddle.net/amitabhjoshi04/zgqt9qzz/4/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
// https://api.jqueryui.com/category/effects/

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        var current = $('#btn1').attr('data-effect');
        var ary = current.split('.');
        if(ary[0]!='clip' && ary[0]!='fade')
            $("#box").effect(ary[0]);
        else{ 
            $("#box").toggle(ary[0]);
            $("#box").toggle(ary[0]);
        }
        ary.push(ary.shift());
        var newstring = ary.join('.');

        $('#btn1').attr('data-effect',newstring);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="btn1" data-effect="bounce.slide.clip.fade">Animate</button>

<div id="box" style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;margin:6px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @Softbyte, I like this. I however want to exec the effect sequentially and some with properties. Any chance you can update your answer with for that?

Comment: Hello @GeraldoIsaaks, I have made few changes to code. Please check feedle url : https://jsfiddle.net/amitabhjoshi04/zgqt9qzz/5/ if you are looking for same or any changes you need ? 
I have added setInterval.